# Webpack - include a static file that's not imported anywhere?

Tags: webpack

My Webpack configuration currently bundles all of the files that i have inside of my `src` folder.

How can i have a static (JSON) file in a `config` folder (same level as the `src` folder) that's not imported anywhere, included in my `build` folder, at the same level as my `main.xxx.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to copy a static file to your build folder with Webpack is to use the `copy-webpack-plugin`, which allows you to copy files or directories from your source folder to your output folder as part of the build process.

To install this plugin:

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then, you need to update your webpack config file. For example:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'app_name'),
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'config' },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

This will copy the `config/config.json` file from your source folder to the `config.json` file in your output folder.

Comment: Thanks but that's giving me an error: `npm run terminated after receiving SIGSEGV signal`

Comment: a SIGSEGV signal error can occur whenever a program tries to access an invalid memory address. This can happen for various reasons, such as dereferencing a null pointer, writing to read-only memory, using an uninitialized pointer, or accessing memory that has been freed or corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, i've read elsewhere that there have been quite a few issues with this plugin starting version 10 onwards. Downgrading to version 9 got rid of this issue.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you fixed problems. :-)